# lag in news ticker (text component move left to right at bottom page smoothly ) not move smoothly in android dynamic view

Tags: java, android, view

I am facing an issue on creating dynamic view with json. The scenario is that i want to create my components like Text, Image and ... from an json. But on rendering newsticker component (the component that show a text and smoothly should change it position in bottom of page) not working properly and it has some lag on moving text.

some of my component are
1-picture
2-textview
3-video  (exoplayer)
4-slider (com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar)
5-webview
6- news tiker (with translate animation)

in my view i have 3 slider , 1 video player , 1 picture ,1 textView and 1 newsTiker at the button in view by adding view like

```
mActivityMainPageBinding.frmMain.addView(textComponent);
```

[image: this is my app profiler]

i have lag with my news ticker

```
  Animation animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
            R.anim.move);
 textView.setAnimation(animation)
 animation.start();
```

and this is my animation

```
 <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:duration="20000"
   android:fromXDelta="-1500"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
   android:repeatCount="infinite"
   android:repeatMode="restart"
   android:toXDelta="1500" />
```